# Return null instead of error for object of null

Tags: javascript

```js
var myVar = null;
console.log(myVar.test)
```

The above code returns this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of null`.
How can I just get it to return null without any errors?

I could use a `try/catch` or an `if` statement to first check `myVar`, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: soon it'll be `myVar?.test`

Comment: Is that Javascript? It doesn't let me add `?` there.

Comment: it is a proposal, that doesnt work yet ;) its a concept present in a lot of modern languages and is called "null propagator"

Comment: `console.log(myVar && myVar.test);` will log `myVar` if it is falsey (including `null`), but will log `myVar.test` if `myVar` is truthy (including any object, except `document.all` in a browser).

Comment: that said: simplest solution is `myVar && myVar.test`. if you have deeper digging with possible nulls to do, use lodash's `get` or similar functions

Comment: Perfect! Just what I'm looking for!

Comment: Also note that in the future you can use [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) (currently stage 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(myvar ? myvar.test : 'myvar is null')
```

You can use an inline ternary operation to check if it's null.

If it's not null, `test` is printed. If it is, `"myvar is null"` is printed. This has the advantage over `myvar && myvar.test` of allowing you to determine the output if `myvar` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I'm looking for.

Comment: @3limin4t0r That also wouldn't work if `myVar.test === 0` or any other falsey value (at least, it would evaluate to "myvar is null" for `myVar = {test:0}`).

Comment: I can confirm that ```myvar={test:0};``` and ```console.log(myvar && myvar.test || 'myvar is null')``` prints ```'myvar is null'```.